# Blocking in-app chat for Walking War Robots iOS at router level?

Tags: ios, war-robots

I'm looking for a way to disable in-game chat for a game on iOS, walking war robots. The kid likes it a lot and I don't want to have the conversation yet about people online.

There's not an iOS setting that is this granular about blocking chat.

My unique situation that makes this feasible is that the iPad he uses is WiFi only and doesn't leave the house. Theoretically, the chat is hitting a separate endpoint / path from the game that I could blacklist at the router level because it's already running DD-WRT.

What I want to know is how do I go about finding the endpoint from the chat so I can try and block it.

Comment: Note that WR chat is really clumsy. You can't just chat with people, you have to invite them to squad first, or you have to join a clan. And joining a clan of unknown people without being able to chat is... unlikely and almost pointless. And people randomly invited to squads don't generally chat much. So I think WR chat is really not a concern for a parent, if you agree with the kid that they should not join a clan (and check it).

Answer (score 1):

In short, you probably can't. It's a very very very longshot, the app using different ports for gameplay and chat. The best way would be to contact the dev and ask for a chat block safety feature.

But if you want to try to find a chat port (if any), just enable traffic logging in your router. Check the log to see which ports the iOS IP is using when running the game / chatting and block them one by one to see if it changes anything. Again, this is very unlikely to work.